# Ionic Tabs not working properly when coming from same module (Ionic tabs)

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic-tabs, tabmenu

I have the case when have 5 tabs at the bottom( home, about, profile, lob/first, lob/second ). first 3 of them are coming from different module and they look great but the last two of them are from the same module and this ones are not ok , when you click on one of them both are selected as active, any suggestion ?

I know there is a way with separating them with different module, but can they come from same module 0
HTML:

```
`<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="quaternary" id="tabs-menu">
  <ion-tab-button tab="home">
  <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="profile" *ngIf="showMyLob">
  <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="about">
  <ion-label>About</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="lob/first">
  <ion-label>First</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>

  <ion-tab-button tab="lob/second">
  <ion-label>SEcond</ion-label>
  </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

  </ion-tabs>
`
` ROUTING TABS MODULE: `const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    canActivate: [OAuthLoginGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/tabs/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: (): Promise<Type<unknown>> => import('../home/home.page.module')
          .then(m => m.HomePageModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'lob/first',
        loadChildren: (): Promise<Type<unknown>> => import('app/lob').then(m => m.LobPageModule),
        canActivate: [OAuthLoginGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'lob/second',
        loadChildren: (): Promise<Type<unknown>> => import('app/lob').then(m => m.LobPageModule),
        canActivate: [OAuthLoginGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        loadChildren: (): Promise<Type<unknown>> => import('../about/about.module')
          .then(m => m.AbnoutModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: (): Promise<Type<unknown>> => import('../profile/profile.module')
          .then(m => m.ProfileModule),
        canActivate: [OAuthLoginGuard],
      },
],
},
]
```

`

is this solvable only if i put the tabs that are samo to another odules?